# How to get a list of possible permutations from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permutation

I need to get an output like X, Y, W avg # is x from a dictionary of lists like this

```
dict = {
    'X': [65, 86, 54],
    'W': [87, 99, 57],
    'Y': [83, 82, 84]
}
```

the output should be what possible permutation from the lists of values has the highest average, and the order of the keys needed to achieve that, with each key only being able to be used once.

I've tried a few solutions but nothing has worked at all.

Here's what I have so far,

```
list = []
for element in zip(dict, *dict.values()):
   list.append(element)
```

this just creates a list of lists where the key is the start of the list, followed by all the numbers in each value as new entries of the list, ex:
X,65,86,54
now I need to find each possible permutation of the three key:value pairs where the lists in each value are combined to find the route with the highest average, like this 87, 86, 84

Comment: show us what you've tried? give us an example output, provide a [mcve] and see [ask]

Comment: I've updated the post, sorry this is my first time posting to stackoverflow, hopefully that works. I really have no idea where to continue from here so I can't add too much info.

Comment: do you need to show all possible permutations or just provide a list with the highest value permutation

Comment: and how is ```87, 86, 84``` the highest average

Answer (score 0):

```
dictt = {
    'X': [65, 86, 54],
    'W': [87, 99, 57],
    'Y': [83, 82, 84]
}



perm = [max([(key,value)  for value in lst],key= lambda i : i[1])for key,lst in dictt.items()]

print(perm)

>>> [('X', 86), ('W', 99), ('Y', 84)]
```

This line `[(key,value)  for value in lst])for key,lst in dictt.items()` returns a list of list with all the values paired with their keys, so

```
[[('X', 65), ('X', 86), ('X', 54)], 
[('W', 87), ('W', 99), ('W', 57)], 
[('Y', 83), ('Y', 82), ('Y', 84)]]
```

I then use `max` and `key= lambda i : i[1]` which gets the maximum number by using the second element in the tuple in this case the number.